# A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

Tags: typescript

Hi I am trying to create a wrapper for an `add` function that is declared like this:

```js
add(target: Object, propName:string, min?: number, max?: number, step?: number): GUIController;
add(target: Object, propName:string, status: boolean): GUIController;
add(target: Object, propName:string, items:string[]): GUIController;
add(target: Object, propName:string, items:number[]): GUIController;
add(target: Object, propName:string, items:Object): GUIController;
```

If I do the following for one of the declarations it works:

```js
add(...args: [Object, string, number?, number?, number?]) {
    return this.gui.add(...args);      <--- this works, but I want to do this for multiple signatures
}
```

So I try to combine different arguments into one.
But I get an error saying `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)`:

```js
type AddArg = 
    [Object, string, number?, number?, number?] |
    [Object, string, boolean] |
    [Object, string, string[]] |
    [Object, string, number[]] |
    [Object, string, Object];

add(...args: AddArg) {
    return this.gui.add(...args);      <--- A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
}
```

Each of the types in `AddArg` is a tuple type, but typescript did not see this, may I know how can I fix this?

An example can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAsAKGkOjABMSAKAFzACcBzZSgLmgHkAjAK2WEoBpoABxrxBAOTAomESjQCWAOzoDEigPwsFAV0TtkNFWAAeG6Nt36BM5INPm9NAJQsAbvDkkA3PiLEyVWgZmNi4efiERcUlkaVlFZWgZMEotCBZ2eHgQZDAFZ2g3D28CIlIKanpGFg5uXgFhUQkpGXklATlKZEQ0lviAbQBdfMKvH1L-CqDq0LqIxujY1oSOrrT7fUHh91GSwjKAyuCasPrIppjetugV7qZj3i2iscJnvwoAOk+AfUC04gUAJ6bbCvXw0RhaGgKYq+AC++HheHwlABgmQ0AAgmQMfRoABeaCvPr3cKXBLrGhqAQUqlmHQONQDaAAHyJJKscSuGSyOQUTNZu2gxJmpM5CTJg35bJFHKW1PpGwGUsFwtqorlITVA2K+GQRkE8BolGgoEgMAAsgD0GaQYKIEg0Bg-ggUNaoK9gPAFC0tLxDeRHLbfL5KAALOQQd7211O-FmZAAdzgDrdEADMKIiNeAHps29yJ93r8WKqTokxfKLJTKwya-pGYHcILc8HwSkodAwxGoymnUX-IXfo5PMHoLmADwAWmnnfDMAThoA1hABOwtMaAJLQBO5Y2UeDQEgHrswABmhugiC0IEockE2UScjoCmSkOQEBzeazgv2g-ofyxEgcToRtQSINtIQUWdu2jR0zX7D5PiHEdg1eRFv3wTCkWwoA)

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wy4gKm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: You could try using the `arguments` object: `return this.gui.add(...arguments)`. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnGAnA5lAvFAUFXUDaA8gEYBWEAxsADRQDOwSAlgHYq0sCuAtsREgH4OPPoOG9+AgLpQAPjjxEylGvUat2UYgHttAGwgBDFjPl4CJclVoNmbG+rb4pphbiVXVtjeNHPX5h4qDnaaliqm2IHh1lCcLHAQAGasEHBSANxYWEnxVEzaLFCGCAAUAHSVhqh0AFywCMgoAJRQAN5uBsBQKJxM9chIhiAAPPCIqAB8GASZbr1MM-iV5dW93BAswHRzbkgQwJxIRQtZAL7ZFIV0+hDletoopSVwpW1QSbr1AETE1d9QM60X6GABe31ojE4EGazSyWCAA)

Comment: @tromgy Thanks for the suggestion, I did not know about this, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't yet seen your playground when I commented, but here's an example how `arguments` can work with those classes you had:

```
type AddArg = 
    [Object, string, number?, number?, number?] |
    [Object, string, boolean] |
    [Object, string, string[]] |
    [Object, string, number[]] |
    [Object, string, Object];

class SomeClass {
    add(..._args: AddArg[]) {
        return;
    }
}

export class MyClass {
    someClass: SomeClass
    constructor() {
        this.someClass = new SomeClass();
    }

    add(...args: AddArg) {
        return this.someClass.add(...arguments);      
    }
}

let a = new MyClass();

a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", 3, 5, 1);
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", 3, 5);
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", 3);
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz");
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", true);
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", ["blah, blah"]);
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", [1, 2, 3]);
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", { bar: "foo"});

// invalid
a.add({ foo: "bar"}, "baz", 3, "blah");
```

Live [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnGAnA5lAvFAsAKCvqAbQHkAjAKwgGNgAaKAZ2CQEsA7FetgVwFtSISAPxc+A4aP6ChAXSgAfXASJlKNek1Yd6pAPa6ANhACGbOYrwESFanUbN2ne1pSEZ5pVdW2ND7VB4pJDcPS3xrNTtNR3pvGhkAblxcKgNjBgYoAGVdXggAYTSMqABvT3xjBAAKADo6gH1jVAYALlgEZFcZAEpS8uUoJAhgbiQ2JLCoAF9cGZxcCAAPMF0kYChU9MyAWRBCrb7JhlyCotbsk-2M-qpdNk1uGlWq3rLJ5WAACxYGGuO8q6ZTBsCAAdwuALOLwmyjm-UqcFqdSaKHO8EQqFe-WUQxGYygXx+f0uZxqCKRZNQfAgbGADG6CQG2EmczhOCM62MGACYKgu0B0OSOGMZOqJSgADN9G0AESkJoyqb0OXGABeMvoAGZ6ABWegARgZuBF5PFUt0svlSEVyvl6q1uqNwtFiLN0qgKutSo9do1UE1TpNYsl7s9Np9aplgZdVTdFojXttkfozG4EGjppD8bD3pV9qIcrSnx0RZlPQmQddWctCtzvvohH19AATFry8aY3Ga4mI-nxVbZebFU7cAB6UdQdgAN2MBhYcA7mfN3fDeb92p9padQA)

Comment: This would work if I can modify the `SomeClass` class, but it is from another library. But thanks for helping